Why does the Laplace transform of the Exponential distribution satisfy this identity?
Let $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\eta)$ and $s > 0$. I would like to know a probabilistic reason why the Laplace transform of $X$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}] = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \eta \, (1- \mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}]) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
I know that $\mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}]$ can be interpreted as the probability that X goes off before a competing $\mathrm{Exp}(s)$ clock, but this doesn't seem to help.
